# webhook url is not copyable which is made by bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, webhooks

### Problem

I can't copy webhook URL from discord client, which is made by bot.
The `Copy Webhook URL` button is disabled.

### What I want to know

- How to make the `Copy Webhook URL` button not disabled which is made by bot
- The reason if the URL of webhook is not copyable which is made by bot

### What happened

I made a webhook using discord.js by this code:

```js
const target: TextChannel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID') as TextChannel;
const result = await target.createWebhook('webhook made by bot')
```

and webhook is created correctly, but I can't copy URL from discord client.
To be precise, I can't click on the `Copy Webhook URL` button. Its disabled.

[image]

Of course, I can get URL from result of `createWebhook` or by fetching webhook info, but I want to allow people who uses the discord client to copy webhook URL easily.

### What I inspected

I tried to look into information of webhooks to see difference between webhooks made by human and bot:

this is info of it made by human

```js
'webhook made by my hand' => Webhook {
  name: 'Spidey Bot',
  avatar: null,
  id: 'id',
  type: 'Incoming',
  guildID: 'guildid',
  channelID: 'channelid',
  owner: undefined
}
```

and this is from bot

```js
'webhook made by bot' => Webhook {
  name: 'webhook made by bot',
  avatar: null,
  id: 'id',
  type: 'Incoming',
  guildID: 'guildid',
  channelID: 'channelid',
  owner: ClientUser {
    id: 'id_of_bot',
    system: null,
    locale: null,
    flags: null,
    username: 'botbotbot',
    bot: true,
    discriminator: 'XXXX',
    avatar: null,
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null,
    verified: true,
    mfaEnabled: false,
    _typing: Map(0) {}
  }
}
```

It looks like there is flag `bot` to identify whether the webhook is made by bot or other.
Can I solve this problem by editing this option?
Can I make it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make the `Copy Webhook URL` button not disabled which is made by bot

From what I know, this is **not** possible. After reading through [Discord Developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook), it doesn't look like the Discord API allows you to make significant changes to the webhooks apart from `name`, `avatar` and `channel_id`.

You won't be able to create a normal webhook (human made) through your bot without it being considered self-botting, which is of course prohibited.

> The reason if the URL of webhook is not copyable which is made by bot

It is a special type of webhook, an **application-owned webhook**, managed by an application (e.g. your discord bot). Purpose of such webhook isn't to be used by regular users.

One of the differences between normal and application-owned webhooks is that application-owned webhooks allow you to send [message components](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components). So unless you are aiming for that, you should be fine with normal webhook.

If your goal is to automatically create webhooks in multiple guilds as part of your bot's features and an application-owned webhook is an absolute need (there is no other way). I would make a command, that will show you a list of webhooks in current channel with their URLs for your users to use (of course with permission checking and privacy, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I got it!
I'll try to get list of channel-webhook list, and make users to check it.